# Microsoft.Net XSD.exe Tool, Creating Instantiated Classes, and XMLSerialization

Tags: xml, visual-studio, xsd, schema, xsd.exe

I have an XML Schema file (xsd) that, serializes out to a file that is exactly how I need the file to look and behave.  However what I want is a top level element, Header specifically, to be Instantiated.  Right now, the source code generated by XSD.exe Just provides me a "Header" property typed as a header object, but it's not instantiated.

Using System.XML.Serialization specifically for serialization of an object from an XML file to a typed object.

So basically, if I try...

```
MyDoc.Header.HeaderField1 = "My value";
```

I get a null reference error.

I have to...

```
MyDoc.Header = new MyApplication.Models.MyDoc.Header();
MyDoc.Header.HeaderField1 = "My value";
```

I'd like to be able to simply have the XSD.exe tool generate the Header object and in the Header property, set the value to = new Header() right from the bat.

Not a big deal, easy to work around, but could be neater.  :-p

Here's basically the Schema I have.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- 
xsd MyDoc.xsd /c /n:MyApplication.Models
-->
<xs:schema xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="MyDoc">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="Header">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="HeaderField1" type="xsd:string" />
              <xsd:element name="HeaderField2" type="xsd:string" />
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
        <xsd:element name="Items">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Item">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                      <xsd:element name="Field1" type="xsd:string" />
                      <xsd:element name="Field2" type="xsd:string" />
                      <xsd:element name="Field3" type="xsd:string" />
                  </xsd:sequence>
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way to approach this is by simply adding a new partial class for MyDoc in code.

So I end up with the generated C# MyDoc.cs file that XSD.exe created.  Then I created a new class file called MyDocPartial.cs.  In that, it looks like...

```
namespace MyApplication.Models
{
    public partial class MyDoc
    {

        public MyDoc()
        {
            this.Header = new MyDocHeader();
        }


    }
}
```

There is a separate Partial Class MyDoc that is generated by XSD.exe.  However it has no defined constructor.  Think I just brain farted here, but also figured I'd share for anyone else.  :)

Note, this partial class is also where I put in all my field mapping code, code to simplify adding Items, etc.  Total brain fart.  Hope it helps.  :)

Answer (score 0):

I created a regex search/replace pattern for automatically converting all property getters from this:

```
 /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
    public AmountType TaxableBase {
        get {
            return this.taxableBaseField;
        }
        set {
            this.taxableBaseField = value;
        }
    }
```

to this:

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public AmountType TaxableBase {
    get {
        if(this.taxableBaseField == null) this.taxableBaseField = new AmountType();
        return this.taxableBaseField;
    }
    set {
        this.taxableBaseField = value;
    }
}
```

To use it, open search/replace with **Ctrl+H**, check .* type, uncheck others, set the scope to Current Document. Write this pattern in search box:
**`(public )(\S+Type)( \S+ {\r\n +get {\r\n)( +)(return )(this.\S+);`**
and this one in replace box:
**`$1$2$3$4if($6 == null) $6 = new $2();\r\n$4$5$6;`**

First you can try replacing one by one. If it works, hit replace all.

If there are enum types in your xsd's classes, it will show warnings in the error panel telling you that they cannot equal null (CS0472).
You can double click each warning then hit Ctrl+X to cut the focused code line. You don't need to move the mouse, simply double click and Ctrl+X repeatedly. It's fast to remove all of them.

It worked perfect for my xsd. May be you'll have to modify the regex pattern to match your types. Specially the **`\S+Type`** part. I used it to distinguish from strings, etc.